# Passing an integer id to post action in controller from angular 4

Tags: angular, rest, model-view-controller, controller, http-post

I am developing angular 4 application using REST services. Currently, I am facing a big problem to make a call to the controller with parameter `id(Integer)`. My controller contains these actions:

```
 Get(), Get(int id), Post([FromBody] Model), Delete(int id)
```

Here, I need one more functionality to implement, that is:

```
_this.http.post(_this.appService.baseUrl + "api/ServiceEmp/'", id).subscribe(result => {});
```

But the code is not working and action in controller receives **ZERO** instead of id value.

Any solution, please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you write

```
_this.http.post(_this.appService.baseUrl + "api/ServiceEmp/'", id).subscribe(result => {});
```

You return a **subscription**, not an Observable.

Try this instead

```
_this.http.post(_this.appService.baseUrl + "api/ServiceEmp/'", id);
```

And make your subscribe in your controller.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [Route("{Id}")]
        public IActionResult Activate(int id) .Action cannot worked.